# Linksys WUSB11 v2.5 - anyway to make it work with WPA?

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there any way to get a Linksys WUSB11 v2.5 adapter to work on a WPA network?
The only option in when trying to connect is WEP.

I have the only driver available from the website, which is from 2002.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [data sheet from Linksys](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/support/WUSB11/download), the WUSB11 only supports WEP 64 & 128.  Usually you cannot add WPA by installing additional software either because of the low-power processors on these types of devices and the complexity of the computations in order to do WPA encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The WUSB11 v2.5 uses an Intersil PRISM <2.5 or 3> chipset. Intersil released drivers that supported WPA (TKIP only) a while back for .. at least some vendors, Microsoft being one of them. Linksys obviously didn't push to update their older drivers.

Anyway, the driver set that Microsoft pushed out to add WPA to their MN-510 (really solid USB adapter, btw) can also be used with other PRISM devices (you just had to add the VID/PIDs for the adapter in the file, which I did). You can grab them [here](http://bit.ly/czBhqz) if you still have a need for them.